# WebAuthenticationBroker NotImplementedException

Tags: raspberry-pi, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I've been testing Windows IoT core on RPI 3, I am working with insider preview, build 10.0.14376.0

For the sake of experiment I chucked our UWP app onto the RPI. Unexpectedly,

```
WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(...);
```

throws NotImplementedException (!!)

I see nothing in the [documentation](http://WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync) that indicates that I should not use this API on windows IoT core. Am I missing something? Are there any other API that aren't implemented yet?

Comment: your link is broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the Windows IoT doc page,

> > Windows IoT Core is a work in progress.

You can find a detailed list of Universal APIs that are not yet available in windows IoT from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/unavailableapis).